# Upload a file via POST using RestSharp

Tags: c#, post, restsharp

I'm trying to simulate a simple multipart HTML form in C#.

I was successful posting text as parameters using the `addParameter` function.
Now I want to upload a file using POST. I tried using the `addFile` function of the `RestRequest` object. But it did not work! I'm getting response code: 0.

Here's my code:

```
//preparing RestRequest by adding server url, parameteres and files...
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("http://" + ipTextBox.Text + "/samplepost/postdata.php", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("msgpost", msgTextBox.Text);
request.AddFile("file1", "NEVER.jpg");

//calling server with restClient
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
{
     if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
          //POST successful
          MessageBox.Show("Success!");                   
     }
     else
     {
          //error ocured during POST
          MessageBox.Show(":-(\nFailed.\nError: " + response.ErrorMessage);
     }
});
```

Please help me find mistakes in my code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As this question has nothing to do with WPF, I have removed the [tag:wpf] tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload File Without Multipart/Form-Data Using RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478663/upload-file-without-multipart-form-data-using-restsharp)

Answer (score 0):

Is NEVER.jpg in the same location as the exe? Because the way you're calling AddFile assumes it is.